# How do I change the sympy preview directory?

Tags: sympy

When I execute

```
sp.preview(expression, viewer = “file”, filename = “expression.png”)
```

SymPy automatically saves the preview in C:\Users\my username.

How do I change the save path?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a canonical way to do this, but you can get the SYMPY_PATH as

```
from sympy.testing.tests.test_code_quality import SYMPY_PATH
```

and at least add that as a prefix to your filename (however your system likes paths added). If that works and puts it in the SymPy directory then you can use any path where you would like the file to go.